# Unit test returns 401 Unauthorized on a permitted route in Spring WebFlux Security

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-test

I am trying to test a route that returns array of objects but the test fails because it returns Unauthorized instead of 200 OK

My test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest(value = CatController.class)
class ContentManagementTestApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;
    
    @MockBean
    CatRepository catRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup(){
        webTestClient=WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context)
                .apply(SecurityMockServerConfigurers.springSecurity())
                .configureClient()
                .build();
    }
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {

    }
    

  @Test
  public void getApprovedCats(){
        webTestClient.get()
                .uri("/cat")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
  }

}
```

And ApplicationSecurityConfig class, has a SecurityWebFilterChain Bean

```
   @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, AuthConverter jwtAuthConverter, AuthManager jwtAuthManager){

        AuthenticationWebFilter jwtFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(jwtAuthManager);
        jwtFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverter);

        return http .csrf().disable()
              .authorizeExchange()

              .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/cat").permitAll()
              
                .anyExchange()
               .authenticated()
               .and()
              .addFilterAt(jwtFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION)
              .formLogin().disable()
               .httpBasic().disable()

               .build();
    }
```

The Error on JUint test shows following

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200 OK> but was:<401 UNAUTHORIZED>
Expected :200 OK
Actual   :401 UNAUTHORIZED

Before test fails and shows Unauthorized, in console it prints
"Using generated security password: 8e5dd468-3fd1-42b6-864a-c4c2ed2227b7"
And I believe that should not be printed since I disabled it in securityFilterChain

Comment: your beans are most likely not loading. Read the docs about how @WebFluxTest works before asking on stack overflow instead of reading some blog posts https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.spring-webflux-tests also post FULL debug logs when asking

Comment: Can you help me fix this ? How can I enable configuration from a non testing file to work when I am running the test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/reactive/WebFluxTest.html) of `@WebFluxTest`:

> Annotation that can be used for a Spring WebFlux test that focuses **only** on Spring WebFlux components.
> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to WebFlux tests

> If you are looking to load your full application configuration and use WebTestClient, you should consider @SpringBootTest combined with @AutoConfigureWebTestClient rather than this annotation.

In other words, when using `@WebFluxTest` in your test, your `SecurityWebFilterChain` is not picked up.

Try annotating your class with `@SpringBootTest` instead.